# How do I put an ASP.Net Framework API made in C# onto Pivotal Cloud Foundry?

Tags: asp.net, rest, asp.net-web-api, cloud-foundry

I created a RestAPI in ASP.Net and need to put it on Cloud Foundry. This is not .NET Core, it is .NET Native. If someone could point me in the right direction that would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pivotal Cloud Foundry has now came up with **windows native tile** for PCF Runtime for Window. Your PCF operator needs to add this tile and then you can host .net native api on to PCF.

After above setup, developers simply “cf push” their app to Windows Server or Linux and PCF does the routing to ensure their code runs in a container, on the right OS. For .NET developers this means full PCF support pushing full, native .NET applications onto Windows

For more info please follow [this](https://content.pivotal.io/blog/welcome-net-native-windows-server-support-in-pcf-1-10)

Apart from that you can simply use **Hosted Web Core Buildpack** to run your core .net app.